# Pandas merge 2 databases based on 2 keys

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to merge 2 pandas df's:

> ISO3 Year Calories
>   AFG 1960 2300
>   AFG 1961 2323
>   ...
>   USA 2005 2800
>   USA 2006 2828

and

> ISO3 Year GDP
>   AFG 1980 3600
>   AFG 1981 3636
>   ...
>   USA 2049 10000
>   USA 2050 10100

I have tried `pd.merge(df1,df2,on=['ISO3','Year'],how=outer)` and many others, but for some reason it does not work, any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pd.merge(df1, df2, on=['ISO3', 'Year'], how='outer')` should work just fine. Can you modify the example, or post a concrete example of df1, df2 which is not yielding the correct result?

```
In [58]: df1 = pd.read_table('data', sep='\s+')

In [59]: df1
Out[59]: 
  ISO3  Year  Calories
0  AFG  1960      2300
1  AFG  1961      2323
2  USA  2005      2800
3  USA  2006      2828

In [60]: df2 = pd.read_table('data2', sep='\s+')

In [61]: df2
Out[61]: 
  ISO3  Year    GDP
0  AFG  1980   3600
1  AFG  1981   3636
2  USA  2049  10000
3  USA  2050  10100

In [62]: pd.merge(df1, df2, on=['ISO3', 'Year'], how='outer')
Out[62]: 
  ISO3  Year  Calories    GDP
0  AFG  1960      2300    NaN
1  AFG  1961      2323    NaN
2  USA  2005      2800    NaN
3  USA  2006      2828    NaN
4  AFG  1980       NaN   3600
5  AFG  1981       NaN   3636
6  USA  2049       NaN  10000
7  USA  2050       NaN  10100
```

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake. The year data have a value for every year. So for some years both a Calories and GDP data point are available. However it does not merge these as one row.

Comment: Even after modifying df1 and df2 to have matching keys, the merge still works as expected for me. It sounds like values which look equal are not actually equal. For example, if `df1['Year']` are integers, but `df2['Year']` are strings, Pandas won't join them as equal. You might want to check `df1.dtypes` and `df2.dtypes` and see that the dtypes match for the `Year` and `ISO3` columns. For string dtypes you may wish to strip whitespace as well: `df['ISO3'] = df['ISO3'].str.strip()`.